# How to plot a function with error bar in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, errorbar

I would like to plot a function `test(x)` with an error bar, where the magnitude of the corresponding errors are saved in the function `error_bar_test(x)`.
The Plot should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have a particular plotting library in mind? Here's a solution with Plots.jl:

```
ulia> using Plots

julia> plot(0:2, [6, 10, 2], yerr = [1, 2, 3], msc = 1, label = "", ytick = 0:2:12)
```

so you need to pass a two vectors with your x and y values and then a vector of the same length as the `yerr` keyword arg. I've also changed the color of the errorbars and the default values of the yticks as well as removed the automatic label for the series. This gives:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another convenient way is to combine Plots.jl with Measurements.jl:

```
using Plots, Measurements
plot(0:2, [6, 10, 2] .± [1, 2, 3])
```

produces

[image]